# Multi module analyse for different languages

Tags: android, .net, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

i have following project structure:

```
src
    backend
        backend.sln
    android-client
        gradlew
```

i have separate analyse configuration: 
**MSBuild runner for c# solution**

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner begin /n:sample /k:sample:backend /v:1.0
msbuild ...
msbuild.sonarqube.runner end
```

and gradle plugin for android project:

```
gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.projectKey=sample:android -Dsonar.projectName=sample -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0
```

this work perfect, but in result i have two different project in sonarqube

can i setup multi-module configuration for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll have to analyze the modules separately, pointing [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) at your C# module and [SonarQube Scanner for Gradle](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle) at the Gradle module. From there you can re-combine them using the Governance($) plugin.